# Which video codec would be most suitable to displaying text?

Tags: video, codec

I am making a video of a CMS in action. Any ideas which codec might be a good idea?

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MS codec offerings - there is one actually optimized for screen playback. As it is a DirectShow codec, adobe should work with it. Flash is another matter, but then tehre you are limtied anyway.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/codecs/video.aspx

has all the normal codecs. Scroll a little down for the Windows Media Video 9 Screen.

I used that for a couple of demonstrations and that worked very nicely - especially as it goes to a lossless thing when not a lot changes, which is VERY typical for demos that do not include games (as most of the screen is actually static).

Playback works on every windows machine.

If you need something platform independant, you basically are out of luck. Nothing there that is screen optimized.

Comment: It's going to get Flashified and put on a website, like all the pretty CS5 videos on the Adobe site. So I'm really looking for a wey to get Premiere to spit out a decent enough file so that Flash can do its worst and it won't look too tragic.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of screen recording software such as [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) which generate Flash videos and take care of the exact formats they are using.